# Stuck at "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_h, _i, _j, _k})." In React Native

Tags: react-native, redux, asyncstorage, redux-persist

This is the file from which error is coming. Detailed Error:

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_h, _i, _j, _k}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

This error is located at:
in MeUI (created by SceneView)

And this is the file from which error is coming: (MeUI.jsx) ->

```
import React from 'react'

import { View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { FlatList } from 'native-base'

import { SWITCH_TO_CHILDSTACK } from '../../../../../Redux/Header/HeaderSwitch'

import AvatarSection from '../../../../components/Profile/AvatarSection'
import Card from '../../../../components/Cards'
import Routes from '../../../../constants/Routes Arrays'

const MeUI = async() => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const { navigate } = useNavigation()
  
  return (
    <View style={{ flex:1, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
      <AvatarSection
        batch={'BCA 6th Sem | 2020-2023'}
        name={'Abbas Ali Dalal'}
      />
      <View style={{ position: 'relative', top: 150, alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <FlatList 
            data={Routes.Me}
            renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> {
              dispatch(SWITCH_TO_CHILDSTACK())
              navigate(item.screen)
            }}>
                <Card.DashboardCard
                    iconName={item.iconName}
                    title={item.title}
                />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            }}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

export default MeUI
```

I Tried deleting the app, cleaned gladle and also cleared data several times in case if it is from Something inside AsyncStorage. But nothing worked...

Also this is my store.js in case something is fault but I have'nt changed anything...
I also use redux-persist.

This is Store.jsx from redux

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import persistReducer from "redux-persist/es/persistReducer";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import authReducer from "./Auth";
import HeaderReducer from "./Header/HeaderSwitch";
import collegeReducer from "./Auth/collegeSelectionSlice";

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    version: 1,
    storage: AsyncStorage,
    blacklist: ['header']
}

const reducers = combineReducers({
    header: HeaderReducer,
    auth: collegeReducer,
    login: authReducer
})

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig , reducers)

const Store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware({
        immutableCheck: false,
        serializableCheck: false
    })
})

export default Store
```

Answer (score 4):

Components can't be async. Your component starts like this:

```js
const MeUI = async() => {
```

Remove the `async` and your component will be valid. If you need to run async code in your component (I can't see any here), define an async function inside or separately from your component.

Comment: No problem, if that worked for you please accept it as an answer, or if you solved it your own way feel free to submit your own answer and accept that.

Comment: This is my first question on SO. So I don’t know many things here…..

Comment: It took me way too long to find the only answer that isn't "Remove the objects from your component" - which wasn't helpful because I had none.